# Small, medium and large jump distances in media player classic

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, media-player, media-player-classic

In the media player classic there this configuration:
[image]

but I can only jump medium distances by left and right arrow keys.

Is there a shortcut key for small and large distances, I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ arrow keys, but doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the left-side menu, navigate to: `Player/keys`, it has all shortcuts of the program, I needed to assign new shortcuts to the commands `Jump Forward/Backward (small/large)`, as they are not bound to shortcuts by default:

[image]

Just make sure that shortcuts you assign,are not assigned to other commands

Answer (score 0):

One pic jump in the movie:

Windows 10, MPC-HC x64: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrow key right or left.